# ALT-TAB showing program with blank name

Tags: alt-tab

A program seems to appearing on my desktop; I don't know the related process. It appears as a blank box, on my desktop.

[image: blank desktop program]

It also appears within the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher without a "name".

[image: blank program alt-tab]

I want to get rid of it, because it's pretty annoying how it overlays on the desktop.

Any ideas on what it is and how to remove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Task Manager "Applications" tab should list window titles. You can look for the blank one and right click on it => "Go To Process"

Alternatively, you can download [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and use the crosshair button ("Find Window's Process"):

[image]

Comment: In the `task manager` it doesn't appear within the `Applications` tab, but ill try `process explorer`.

Comment: The `process explorer` does the trick, it was a `Razer` application, RzSnapse.exe. Thanks! @Bob